# trying to multiply subtotal with a shipping % to get grand total

Tags: php, mysql

coming from the cart i have two options one for check and one for paypal

one i need to display the fees of the total price as a shipping and handling charge

```
 <td><form id="formb" name="formb" method="post" action="checkout_paypal.php" onSubmit="return checkouttwo();">
                  <span class="TextA">Pick-up date:</span>
                  <input name="PICKUP1" type="text" class="TextA" id="PICKUP1" size="20" />
<input type="hidden" name="memberid" value="<?echo$_SESSION['memberid']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cart" value="<?echo$wcart?>">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?echo$SHOWMEQ?>">

                <label>
                  <input name="button" type="submit" class="TextB" id="button" value="Pay by Paypal" />
                  </label>
              </form></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" class="TextB">Total: $<?echo$SHOWMEQ?></td>
                  <td valign="top"><span class="TextB">Shipping & Handling Fee: $</span><br />
                    <span class="TextB">Total: $<?echo$GETMYTOTAL?></span></td>
```

that would my code be to add that 3% shipping and handling charge in there so it can carry down to my total?

Comment: If you're using short tags anyway, you can echo a variable like this `<?=$var?>`

Comment: can i add a percentage in there? then have the <?echo$SHOWMEQ?> * ?% to equal the gettotal?

Comment: `<?php echo $SHOWMEQ * $tax; ?>` ?

Comment: how would i explain what the $tax =? or since i am trying to make it * 3% would i have to disclaim it somewhere?

Comment: No, you don't have to declare it. If you don't want it to be set to a variable, just put the decimal in place of `$tax` in the line above.

Comment: <?php echo $SHOWMEQ * 3%; ?> <<can it be like that?

Comment: i get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/florida/public_html/checkout.php on line 293

Comment: That's because the `%` sign means [modulus](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php). You need to convert 3% into a decimal value.

Comment: nvm i got it ty, just need to figure out how to add it to the total

Comment: Glad to hear you got it. Might as well just delete this question. It's probably not going to help anyone else in the future.

Comment: Add it to the total? You mean multiply the total by 1.03? Remedial classes anyone!

Comment: Please do not write a number in your calculation. Define a constant in your script and use that, or better: define the tax rate in a configuration file or database table. Look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants

Answer (score 0):

Ryan,

You just have to write

```
<span class="TextB">Total: $<?php echo ($SHOWMEQ*3/100)+$SHOWMEQ;?></span>
```

It will display total amount along with 3% shipping and handling charges.